# Horizontal View line not displaying in RecyclerVeiw

Tags: android, view, colors, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I am using Horizontal Recycler View :

My Layout file contains recyclerview as below :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_Styles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

My custom/singleview/raw file to be bind in RecyclerView is as below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/txt_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10"
    android:text="Style"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<View
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/viewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_style"
    android:background="@color/colorAppDefault" />
<!--#455A90-->
```

My **viewStyle** is display when I am giving its width to Fix. But, Its look improper.

What might be the issue ? 
I am doing as below in My Adapter.

```
   public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt_style = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_style);
            viewStyle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewStyle);
        }

        public void setData(DrinkStyleModel modelBeerStyle, final int position) {
            final DrinkStyleModel modelFinal = modelBeerStyle;
            if (modelFinal.is_check()) {
                txt_style.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                viewStyle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                txt_style.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
                viewStyle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by the view being Improper

Comment: Its width should be same as TextView width. or Should be Same as width of Root parent of raw layout. By giving fix its displaying fix size no matter textview is 2 characters long or 20.

Comment: I have given TextView width to wrap_content.